# QML Model data by index

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I have QAbstractListModel based model...

```
class RecordModel : public QAbstractListModel { ... };

QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("recordModel", &model);

// QML
recordModel.get(0).name // now work
```

How to get a model data by index and role name?

... **Solution**:

```
// C++
class RecordModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_ENUMS(Roles)

   public:
      // ...
      Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(int i, int role) const
      {
          return data(index(i, 0), role);
      }
};

// QML
recordModel.data(0, RecordModel.NameRole);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should only use a Q_INVOKABLE method for specific functionalities that you want to be able to call from QML. Unless you somehow want to access model data from without access to the *delegate* of your model, you should always use the more proper model<->delegate way of getting the data.

Since you're inheriting from QAbstractListModel, it'll work like QAbstractItemModel.

Declare roles as shown:

```
enum Roles {
    RoleA = Qt::UserRole + 1,
    RoleB = Qt::UserRole + 2
};
```

Override this method to allow QML access using roles:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> RecordModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[RoleA] = _Ut("roleA");
    roles[RoleB] = _Ut("roleB");
    return roles;
}
```

Override this method to return data when QML tries to access:

```
QVariant RecordModel::data(const QModelIndex &modelIndex, int role) const
{
    QVariant rv;
    int index = modelIndex.row();

    switch( role ) {
    case RoleA:
        rv = "A";
        break;
    case RoleB:
        rv = "B";
        break;
    default:
        DASSERT(FALSE);     // Unexpected role.
        break;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

Then in QML you'll simply use "roleA" and "roleB" in the delegates of the QML Element that uses this model to access the data.

References:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractlistmodel.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Q_INVOKABLE method:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getRecord(int iIndex)
{
    return QVariant::fromValue<CRecord*>((CRecord*)this->at(iIndex));
}
```

And then in QML:

```
recordModel.getRecord(0)
```

You will just need to declare a metatype:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( RecordModel* )
```

And somewhere in main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<RecordModel>("PrivateComponents", 1, 0, "RecordModel");
qmlRegisterType<CRecord>("PrivateComponents", 1, 0, "CRecord");
```