# QML TableView: How do you only display a subset of model index data?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, tableview

I want to display a subset of columns from an large existing C++ `TableModel` in a new QML `TableView`.

All the [documenation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) and examples I've read override `QAbstractItemModel::roleNames()` to expose model data associated with the roles as properties in QML.

The problem is that the legacy `TableModel`'s `data()` function has a complex implementation tightly coupled to `Qt::DisplayRole`:

```cpp
\\...
QVariant LegacyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) {
    switch(role) {
    \\...
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
        switch(LegacyTableColumn.at(index.column())) {
            \\ lots of stuff
        }    
    }
    \\...
}
\\...
```

As such, I'd prefer to avoid overriding `QAbstractItemModel::roleNames()` as it will mean substantial refactoring of the above `data()` function.

I have a QML view showing *all* the columns in each model row:

```js
TableView {
    anchors.fill: parent

    model: LegacyModel

    delegate: RowLayout {
        implicitWidth: parent.width

        Text {
            text: model.display // i.e., inferred from Qt::DisplayRole
                                // can I access column data here somehow?
        }
    } 
}
```

But I only want to display a small set of columns.

Is there a way to do that without overriding `roleNames()` and using those as properties in the view?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: it's a conceptual question, not a reproducible problem. is their something specifically unclear about it?

Comment: No, it is not only conceptual since you indicate: *But I only want to display a small set of columns.* so you have a code that has an error since the role "display" should cover what you want but it seems that your model is very peculiar

Comment: It's hard to simplify the model as that `data()` function is ~300 lines of legacy code. To clarify more: `model.display` displays the whole _row_ of data. Is their a way to display a single column (i.e., something like `model.display[2]` etc.) without resorting to custom roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell it looks like the only way to avoid custom roles is to hack a `Q_INVOKABLE` function in the model:

```cpp
// LegacyModel.h:
...
Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getMyData(int row, int column) const { return m_data[row][column]; }
...
```

```js
// TableView.qml:

TableView {
    ...
    model: LegacyModel

    delegate: RowLayout {
        ...
        Text {
            text: model.getMyData(row, 2) 
                                
        }
        Text {
            text: model.getMyData(row, 5) 
                                
        }
        // etc.
    } 
}
```

Not a great solution, so I'm going to create a new model with custom roles insted.

Related:

[How to implement QML ListModel like get method for an QAbstractListModel derived model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711421/how-to-implement-qml-listmodel-like-get-method-for-an-qabstractlistmodel-derived#25652320)

[How to access ListView's current item from qml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389831/how-to-access-listviews-current-item-from-qml/31206992#31206992)

[How to access Items stored in a QAbstractListmodel in QML(by delegates) otherwise than using item roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423372/how-to-access-items-stored-in-a-qabstractlistmodel-in-qmlby-delegates-otherwis/14424517#14424517)

[QML Model data by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398646/qml-model-data-by-index#20399542)